# Change class attribute type from string to int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this class that should be initialized with all parameter `int` but sometimes it gets `string` instead of `int`

```
@dataclass
class Meth:
    one: Optional[int] = None
    two: Optional[int] = None
    three: Optional[int] = None


my_class = Meth(one="1",two=2,three=None)
```

As you can see in attribute `one` there is bad type.
And to fix this my first thought was to create it again like this

```
new_class = Meth(one=int(my_class.one),two=int(my_class.two),three=int(my_class.three)
```

but I get this error because three is None

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object, or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

So my question is what would be the best way to change all attribute types to the correct type.

Comment: I'd suggest you to go one step back and check how do you end up with arguments of wrong type. It's a lame way to write code which will normalize wrong input from other part of code.

Comment: @OlvinRoght i get it from API so there is no way to fix that

Comment: Does it come in JSON format?

Comment: @OlvinRoght basically its part of the query string, so it's a string

Comment: So you can try to convert each of them to `int` and pass to constructor only those which can be converted.

Comment: Something like [this](https://tio.run/##fY7BCsIwDIbveYrQ0zbGQL3IYOALqA8gInXrtrKtLW2YiPjss6voTppDyJf/z0/MnVqtNltjp6m2esCKEy977pxwKAejLS0rCA66G6maj3g0JLXiPcBu8YWOe0FtDuhLK5F/nSep6IwFHvw2qHTT/9TWil/XANw2ztODeWQ5shVLkfnAeV7zAPP9jNeet@wJStwu7/@K8GGUJI8uRx8bjTHW2mKX4ugZ5@xMkhhcFKOsccykq0QpB95H8TMGmKYX) *(oversimplified)*.

Comment: If possible then add the actual one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused when converting None to int, not because of specified types. You can add a check:

```
new_class = Meth(
   one=int(my_class.one),
   two=int(my_class.two),
   three=my_class.three if my_class.three is None else int(my_class.three)
)
```

---

A better way would be to do it while initializing the class

```
class Meth:
    one: int = None
    def __init__(self, 
            one: Optional[Union[str,int]] = None,
            two: Optional[int] = None,
            three: Optional[int] = None):
    # Do the checks and assign values
    if one is not None:
        self.one = int(one)
```

Or by using a library for data validation, pydantic or alike:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Meth(BaseModel):
    one: int
    two: Optional[int]
    three: Optional[int]

my_class = Meth(one="1",two=2,three=None)
assert type(my_class.one) is int
```

Comment: well then i have to check all , because all of them can be string , int or None, and in real-world scenarion i have 6 of attributes, it's just a simplified version here